# How to implement a navigation button in shared application resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I'm currently trying to create a simple app that pulls data from an API I made and displays it in a list. You are then supposed to be able to click the list items to be navigated to a detailed view page with an image viewer etc. For that to work I need to navigate to a page called `PlanViewer.xaml` (currently only available for the Windows Phone app part, will do for both though).

For my list to work I built the following data template in my shared `App.xaml`:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PlanDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="NavigatePlan" Tag="{Binding FilePath}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding LastUpdate}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I apply it in my `MainPage.xaml` as shown here:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PlanList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlanDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PlanItems}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I can't bind any events to the button in the `App.xaml`, so I think I need to use an `ICommand` interface. I might also have a much more fundamental mistake in how I built this thing so far.

TL;DR for my goal: I want to adjust the datatemplate so that every button links to a page `PlanViewer.xaml` with an argument describing which plan is supposed to be shown (e.g. ID or file path).

Comment: You need to have your Model, ViewModel and Databinding set correctly.  For the button, I would bind a Command to the ViewModel.  Once that Command triggers, it should take the data from the CommandParameter of the button and then finally navigate to your second page.  As you can see, all this requires quite a bit of knowledge to even get started.  I will provide some example code for you when I get home.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an Universal App solution.  It's can view as basically a tutorial on Model, View,and ViewModel.

I don't know what UI Element you want to use, but for this I going to pick a one that is supported in both Windows 8.1 and WP 8.1.  The ListView,  so in both Project's MainPage.xaml lets define that.

---

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Song}"></TextBlock>
                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=DataContext.SimpleCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Extra}"
                        x:Name="mybutton" Width="200" Height="50" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Content="Click Me"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As you can see, I databinded the Button with a **Command** and a **CommandParameter**.  The command is the function in the ViewModel that I want to execute when the user clicks the button.  The CommandParameter is a object you want to pass to your Command function.  In your case, your TAG.

---

Namespaces

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;              // ObservableCollection
using System.Windows.Input;                        // ICommand
```

---

Now lets defined a Command (Should be part of the Shared Project)

```
public class MySimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // do stuff based off your tags
        string tag = parameter as string;
        if(tag == "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT")
        {
        }

        // void of the trigger libraries, lets make this simple
        // navigate to your page
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YOUR_PAGE));

    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

---

Now lets setup a simple model (Should be part of the Shared Project)

```
public class sample_model
{
    public sample_model(string artist, string song, string extra = "")
    {
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.Song = song;
        this.Extra = extra;
    }

    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Song { get; set; }
    public string Extra { get; set; }         // this is your tag
}
```

---

Now lets setup a ViewModel for our ListView(s) to use. (Should be part of the Shared Project)

```
public class sample_viewmodel
{
    public sample_viewmodel()
    {
        this.DataSource = CreateData();

        this.SimpleCommand = new MySimpleCommand();  // create the command
    }

    // create a static list for our demo
    private ObservableCollection<sample_model> CreateData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<sample_model> my_list = new ObservableCollection<sample_model>();
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Body of Christ", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Christ Again", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "A Night With the Lord", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Touch Me Jesus", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "I Found Jesus (With Someone Else)", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Savior Self", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Christ What a Day", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Three Times My Savior", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Jesus Touched Me", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Lord is my Savior", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "I Wasn't Born Again Yesterday", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Pleasing Jesus", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Jesus (Looks Kinda Hot)", "A Track"));
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("Butters", "What What", "B Track"));
        return my_list;            
    }

    public ICommand SimpleCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<sample_model> DataSource{ get; set; }

}
```

---

And finally, lets link the ListView to our ViewModel which should bind the "Artist, Song, and Button (Command & CommandParamters)".  I usually do this in each Page's Load function.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sample_viewmodel viewmodel = new sample_viewmodel();  // create the view model
    myListView.DataContext = viewmodel;                   // set the datacontext (this will link the commands)
    myListView.ItemsSource = viewmodel.DataSource;        // set the ItemsSource, this will link the Artist,Songs
}
```

---

There you have it, each time the user clicks on the button no matter what platform it will perform the Command function.

Sample Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I love you so much right now. I haven't had the time to continue my app yet, but your post is literally the first time I ever understood how I use commands, and how I can make these kinda list views in universal projects. Seriously, thanks for all the detail and description!

Comment: You are welcome.  :), Don't worry it took me awhile to figure out XAML and Databinding myself.

Comment: ViewModel without implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged is not good example.

Comment: @user2250152 You don't have to implement INotify, the ObservableCollection<T> will handle this for you.