# Windows Phone 8.1 - Menu flyout item click command c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am writing an application for Windows Phone 8.1, and I wanted to use a flyout on listView item. Because I am doing my best to write nice app, I am trying to use MVVM pattern and resource dictionaries with templates insead of all xaml in one page. 
However, I can't bind my MenuFlyoutItem Command - it seems like it doesn't see the datacontext of the page, or it has some other dataContext. Here is some code:

1) My template in a separate resource dictionary:

```
<Grid Margin="0, 0, 0, 10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
            <converters:EmptyDateConverter x:Key="EmptyDateConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <icore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
                <converters:OpenMenuFlyoutAction />
            </icore:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="AddToCalendarMenuItem" Command="{Binding AddToCalendar}" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ThumbnailUri}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource ListItemTitle}"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock x:Uid="DvdReleaseDate" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DvdRelease, Converter={StaticResource EmptyDateConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

2) And here is the list view:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SearchListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SearchList}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchListTemplate}" SelectionChanged="NavigateToMovieDetails"  />
```

My ViewModel is a static kind of singleton in the app.xaml.cs

I've tried to create a new instance of the VM in xaml, but it didn't work - maybe I was doing smth wrong.

I would really appreciate Your help! Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Roman

Comment: If that Grid is your `<ItemTemplate>` and you're binding that Command that way, that would mean you will need a Command for every model you put in your ViewModel.  So where ever you put that "DvdRelease" there should be also a Command.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, I think though it breaks the MVVM design - logic should be in viewModel and not in model

Comment: It would be better if it was in the ViewModel.  If you want to implement it that way, I have a nice tutorial on how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927

Comment: Thank You very much - it worked and it doesn't violate MVVM principles!

Comment: Np, I will link the Tutorial as an answer, so people can see it better.  Please mark it as a solution, so it doesn't show up on my not answer page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick with that `<ItemTemplate>` you will have to have a Command per every Model in your ViewModel, which is not ideal.

To set a single Command and have a CommandParameter see this SO Tutorial I made it is too much code to type here:

[Implement a ViewModel Single Command with CommandParamater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927)

Answer (score 0):

@Chubosaurus Software following your approach I came up with this.

Here is a `ListView` bound to a list of todo items placed inside a `DataTemplate` which contains a `TextBlock` having a `MenuFlyout` to show edit, delete context menu kind of thing.

The key to bind the commands in the view model to the `MenuFlyoutItem` is to give the `ListView` a name and do element binding using the `ElementName` property in the `Command` to point to the ListView's name. To access the commands in our view model we've to go through the ListView's `DataContext` and bind it to a command on it because the `DataContext` of the `MenuFlyoutItem` is an item in the `ItemsSource`

The MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWA.MenuFlyout.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWA.MenuFlyout"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="using:UWA.MenuFlyout.ViewModels"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:common="using:UWA.MenuFlyout.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Margin="24,24">
        <ListView x:Name="Todos" ItemsSource="{Binding Todos}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Action}">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="edit" 
                                                Command="{Binding ElementName=Todos, Path=DataContext.EditTodo}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="delete" 
                                                Command="{Binding ElementName=Todos, Path=DataContext.DeleteTodo}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
                                <common:OpenMenuFlyoutAction/>
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="RightTapped">
                                <common:OpenMenuFlyoutAction/>
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The MainPage.xaml.cs is where the DataContext of the MainPage is set.

```
namespace UWA.MenuFlyout
{
    using UWA.MenuFlyout.ViewModels;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
    }
}
```

The MainViewModel.cs containing the Todos which is an ObservableCollection type and the EditTodo and DeleteTodo commands.

```
namespace UWA.MenuFlyout.ViewModels
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using UWA.MenuFlyout.Core;
    using UWA.MenuFlyout.Models;

    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ICommand editTodo;

        private ICommand deleteTodo;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Todos = new ObservableCollection<TodoModel>
            {
                new TodoModel { Id = 1, Action = "Buy Milk", IsDone = true },
                new TodoModel { Id = 2, Action = "Buy Groceries", IsDone = false }
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TodoModel> Todos { get; set; }

        public ICommand EditTodo
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.editTodo == null)
                {
                    this.editTodo = new RelayCommand(this.OnEditTodo);
                }

                return this.editTodo;
            }
        }

        public ICommand DeleteTodo
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.deleteTodo == null)
                {
                    this.deleteTodo = new RelayCommand(this.OnDeleteTodo);
                }

                return this.deleteTodo;
            }
        }

        public void OnEditTodo(object parameter)
        {
            // perform edit here
            var todo = parameter as TodoModel;
        }

        public void OnDeleteTodo(object parameter)
        {
            // perform delete here
            var todo = parameter as TodoModel;
        }
    }
}
```

The Model

```
namespace UWA.MenuFlyout.Models
{
    public class TodoModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Action { get; set; }

        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The BaseViewModel which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
namespace UWA.MenuFlyout.Core
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A simple ICommand implementation.

```
namespace UWA.MenuFlyout.Core
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> action;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.action(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

The OpenMenuFlyoutAction which implements DependencyObject and IAction to open the MenuFlyout by using the Execute method on the IAction interface.

```
namespace UWA.MenuFlyout.Core
{
    using Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

    public class OpenMenuFlyoutAction : DependencyObject, IAction
    {
        public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
        {
            var frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            var flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(frameworkElement);
            flyoutBase.ShowAt(frameworkElement);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```