# How to add things to a ListBox after setting its DataBinding?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating a windows Phonw 8.1 app. I have a ListBox and I want to append/insert other at runtime when I click a button. But it doesn't work or it crashes.

I my page's constructor I have this:

```
myData = new List<Stuff>() {
    new Stuff(){Name="AAA"},
    new Stuff(){Name="BBB"},
    new Stuff(){Name="CCC"},
    new Stuff(){Name="DDD"},
};
myListBox.DataContext = myData;
```

My page's xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="Transparent">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Ok, this work well, when I launch the app I can see the list with its 4 items.

```
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myData.Add(new Stuff() { Name = String.Format("Added item #{0}", myData.Count) });

    //I tried to set the DataContext again, but it does nothing
    myListBox.DataContext = mydata;

    //I tried to tell the the list to redraw itself, in winform, the Invalidate() method usually get the job done, so I tried both
    myListBox.InvalidateMeasure()
    //and / or
    myListBox.InvalidateArrange();
    //or
    myListBox.UpdateLayout();

    //I tried
    myListBox.Items.Add("Some text");
    //or
    myListBox.Items.Add(new TextBlock(){Text="Some text"});
    //or 
    (myListBox.ItemsSource as List<Stuff>).Add(new Stuff(){Name="Please work..."});
}
```

And the best the can can happen is to throw an Exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

I've also used a ListView instead, but nothing changes. Bonus question: what is the difference between a ListBox and a ListView?

Google is not really helping, the stuff I find is probably for old version of Windows Phone or normal WPF or ASP.Net...

Also, a weird thing that happens is after adding an item to the list and nothing happen, when I click on an old item, I get a catastrophic failure. I don't have event on my list items yet.

I'm about to give up with data binding, and just build my app piece by piece by code. It should not be that hard to add stuff to a list, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to implement something with `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface either do it yourself or you use a class that has it built in.

[MSDN INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Stuff
{
    public Stuff(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


ObservableCollection<Stuff> myData = new ObservableCollection<Stuff>();


myData.Add(new Stuff("abcd"));
```

Comment: I'll change my code to use ObservableCollection<T> and I'll remember INotifyPropertyChanged for when I work on the parts of my app that are actually usefull :)

Suppose that I don't have control of the source code (in a dll), ie: a class Stuff that has a List<OtherStuff>. How can I tell my app that the DataContext of a FrameworkElement has changed?

Comment: @GuillaumeGrillonLabelle It will be pretty difficult if you don't have the source code or they didn't implement a callback function/delegate.  Best, I can give you is to refresh the list (buffer) and add/remove any differences and update ObserableCollection.  You might want to read up on MVVM patterns a bit, I have a very basic example read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927