# Get ListBox DataContext from UserControl

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a UserControl with a button inside it. The UserControl its DataContext is one of my models so I can bind to it. However, for the button I want to be able to call a method from my viewmodel. The DataContext of the ListBox is this ViewModel.

Because my ContextMenu also needs the same DataContext I've bound them like this:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AttendEventCommand, ElementName=EventListBox}"
```

Calling the EventListBox element and using its DataContext to call the AttendEventCommand. However I would like to call the AttendEventCommand from a button on the UserControl. I tried doing it the same way but sadly it doesn't work.

My data context is set like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=EventList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}
```

My listbox code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="EventListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Occurrences}" Margin="0,50,0,0" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <uctl:EventListItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="auto">
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True" x:Name="ContextMenu">
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Going" Header="{Binding AttendingText}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AttendEventCommand, ElementName=EventListBox}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                </uctl:EventListItem>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And my UserControl's button:

```
<Button Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="5" Opacity="0" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AttendEventCommand, ElementName=EventListBox}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code that you actually set the DataContext of the ListBox.  `ItemsSource != DataContext`, thus that binding that you have for the Command will never work.

Comment: I omitted that part of the code because it seemed obvious to me that that I would've set that DataContext in the firstplace. I have added my line of code setting the datacontext to the example for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is not that what you want to do is not working; instead, your design appears to be wrong.

What you have now is like this:
You have a `Window` that has a `DataContext` and a `ListBox`. The `ListBox` has an `ItemsSource`, which we'll assume is some `IEnumerable<Occurrence>`.

The appearance of each item in your `ListBox` is an `EventListItem`, which is a `UserControl` that contains at least one `Button`.

*You want this `Button`'s `Command` to call a method on your `Window`'s `DataContext`.*

This last sentence is wrong. The fact that the item has the button implies that it does something that is related to the item, not the window contents. If this is not true, then the visual design of the window and listbox items should probably be reconsidered.

If the button is in fact affecting the item, then you should not call a method on your `Window`'s `DataContext`, but instead call a method on your item's `DataContext`.

The solution is to wrap your model object `Occurrence` in a view model class of its own. Let's call it `OccurrenceViewModel`. Your `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` would be some form of `IEnumerable<OccurrenceViewModel>`. Because it's a view model, it's allowed to implement `Command` methods, which can then in one way or another manipulate the `Occurrence`, either directly or preferably by passing it to some class that implements the use case.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext` of your `EventListItem` will be a Model of your `ItemsSource` because it is part of the `DataTemplate`.  So you have to set it explicitly.

Refer to [How to implement a navigation button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927) for some of the code I'll be using as a solution.

---

Lets assume your custom `UserControl`is very basic like so:

```XAML
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SimpleCommand}" CommandParameter="1"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Where SimpleCommand is the Command you want to call in the Top View Model.

Then you have to change your `DataTemplate` to

```XAML
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <uctl:EventListItem
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myListBox}"/>
        <!-- more xaml -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Your `<toolkit:ContextMenu>` should work as is.

---

Put a break point at the Execute function of the `ICommand` and you will see it will get
hit there everytime.

```C#
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
   // logic to execute when user hits the command
   int debug_var = 0;   // put a break point here
}
```

Comment: I have other items in the UserControl that do need to be bound to the ItemSource, by changing the DataContext of the whole UserControl this would break. Thank you for the answer nonetheless.