# WP Binding Button Command in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Im tring to create a button in a datatemplate usually its

```
  <Button x:Name="SomeButton" Click="SomeButton_Click"></Button> //XAML
  <private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  //CS
 {
     // Code
 }
```

But i can't seem to firgure out how to this with a simple button in a datatemplate all a want to do is open a popup from MainPage.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in a `<DataTemplate>` best bind your action to `Command` and `CommandParameter` inside your ViewModel

```XAML
<Button Command="{Binding myCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Extra}"
        x:Name="mybutton" Width="200" Height="50"/>
```

---

Full example using a ListView / MVVM

[MVVM ListView + Command Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927)