# listpicker shows object name instead of property I try all solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8

listpicker shows object name instead of property.**I'm already try all the solution which already given in stackoverflow** but i dn't get any result

```
                 BorderThickness="0.2" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="AreaClassification_SelectionChanged"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="204,-53,0,0"  BorderBrush="Black" >
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="18"                    Foreground="White"   />                                                  
                                                                                  </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I just need to learn how to design a control.any reference do you have?

CodeBehind

```
 string result = e.Result;
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
                var results = o["Data"]["Area"];
                JArray obj = results as JArray;
                var dt = obj.ToArray();
                foreach (var d in dt)
                {
                    Area dts = new Area();
                    dts.code = Convert.ToString(d["code"]);
                    dts.name = Convert.ToString(d["name"]);
                    _lst.Add(dts);
                }
                AreaClassification.ItemsSource = _lst;
```

Comment: Please share your code behind.

Comment: You need to implement a MVVM approach.  Also you can only DataBind to a property of a class.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927 where the solution I provided is a simple MVVM tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research i found this

```
 AreaClassification.SummaryForSelectedItemsDelegate += SummarizeTeams;
protected string SummarizeTeams(IList selection)
        {
            string str = "*None Selected*";

            if (null != selection && selection.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
                int idx = 0;
                foreach (object o in selection)
                {
                    if (idx > 0) contents.Append(", ");
                    contents.Append(((Area)o).name);
                    idx++;
                }
                str = contents.ToString();
            }

            return str;
        }
```

To Show List Of Item We Need to use SummaryForSelectedItemsDelegate method on c#.I hope It's will help others