# C# Databinding ListView not working - Windows 10 Universal

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I have a Database from where I grab my "Baustellen". Now I want to Show their "strasse" on a ListView via DataBinding but they do not Show up. Do you have any idea why?

Baustelle.cs:

```
namespace SchlachterFliesen.Code
{
   public class Baustelle
   {
    public int id;
    public Kunde bauherr;
    public Kunde auftraggeber;
    public Ort ort;
    public string strasse, hausnr, bauauftrag, status;

    public Baustelle()
    {

    }

    public Baustelle(int id, Kunde bauherr, Kunde auftraggeber, Ort ort, string strasse, string hausnr, string bauauftrag, string status)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.bauherr = bauherr;
        this.auftraggeber = auftraggeber;
        this.ort = ort;
        this.strasse = strasse;
        this.hausnr = hausnr;
        this.bauauftrag = bauauftrag;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            "Baustelle@" + GetHashCode() + "\r\n" +
            "ID: " + id + "\r\n" +
            "Bauherr: " + bauherr?.name + "\r\n" +
            "Auftraggeber: " + auftraggeber?.name + "\r\n" +
            "Ort: " + ort?.name + "\r\n" +
            "Straße: " + strasse + "\r\n" +
            "Hausnummer: " + hausnr + "\r\n" +
            "Bauauftrag: " + bauauftrag + "\r\n" +
            "Status: " + status;                 
    }
  }
}
```

Baustelle.xaml.cs

```
namespace SchlachterFliesen
{
/// <summary>
/// Eine leere Seite, die eigenständig verwendet oder zu der innerhalb eines Rahmens navigiert werden kann.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class Baustelle : Page
{
    private List<Code.Baustelle> Baustellen;
    public Code.Baustelle[] baustellen;

    public Baustelle()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Daten.LadeAlleBaustellen(new Daten.Ziel<Code.Baustelle[]>(empfaenger));  //HERE I GRAB THEM!


    }

    public void empfaenger(Code.Baustelle[] baustellen)
    {
        this.baustellen = baustellen;
        Baustellen = GetBaustellen();
    }

    public List<Code.Baustelle> GetBaustellen()
    {
        var baustellenListe = new List<Code.Baustelle>();

        if (baustellen.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < baustellen.Length; i++)
            {
                baustellenListe.Add(new Code.Baustelle(baustellen[i].id, baustellen[i].bauherr, baustellen[i].auftraggeber, baustellen[i].ort, baustellen[i].strasse, baustellen[i].hausnr, baustellen[i].bauauftrag, baustellen[i].status));
            }
        }
        //myTextBlock.Text = res;
        return baustellenListe;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        currentView.BackRequested += backButton_Tapped;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        currentView.BackRequested -= backButton_Tapped;
    }

    private void backButton_Tapped(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var mainPage = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;


        if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Baustelle.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="SchlachterFliesen.Baustelle"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SchlachterFliesen"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data ="using:SchlachterFliesen.Code"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Frame Name="baustelleFrame">
        <Grid>
            <ListView Name="baustellenListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Baustellen}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Baustelle">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind strasse}"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </Grid>
    </Frame>        
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Have a look at my minimal example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613212/how-to-implement-a-navigation-button-in-shared-application-resources/25627927#25627927  it's for WUA8.1, but it should still work for your W10 project.

Comment: What are the `Daten.LadeAlleBaustellen` and `Daten.Ziel<Code.Baustelle[]>`? As your code is incomplete, I can't reproduce your issue. Could you share a [mcve]? Besides, have you tried setting `Baustellen` in constructor like `Baustellen = new List<Baustelle> { new Baustelle { strasse = "1" }, new Baustelle { strasse = "2" }, new Baustelle { strasse = "3" } };`， does this work?

Answer (score 0):

The values "strasse, hausnr, bauauftrag, status" need to be properties, e.g. public Strasse { get; set; } instead and then bind to those, that should work - you might need to set the data source of the list to be the list of items as well.

Comment: I set {get;set} behind them but it still does not work.

Comment: When using x:Bind, they don't have to be properties.

Comment: Good to know that, something I've always assumed but glad to know otherwise when using that method of binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ObservableCollection<Baustelle>` instead of a `List<Baustelle>`.

Comment: Not necessary. Any IEnumerable will do, unless you want to pick up dynamic changes to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I've pasted your code into a fresh app, making minimal tweaks to make it compile outside your environment. The bindings work just fine:

[image]

I don't have access to the code you're using to load your data, so I tweaked the code a bit, like so (renaming the page so it doesn't have the same name as your model class):

```
public BaustellePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Empfänger(
        new Baustelle(1, "herr 1", "auf 1", "ort 1", "strasse 1", "42", "50", "good"),
        new Baustelle(2, "herr 2", "auf 2", "ort 2", "strasse 2", "42", "50", "good"),
        new Baustelle(3, "herr 3", "auf 3", "ort 3", "strasse 3", "42", "50", "good"));

}

public void Empfänger(params Baustelle[] baustellen)
{
    this.baustellen = baustellen;
    Baustellen = GetBaustellen();
}
```

(I also replaced `Kunde` and `Ort` with `string`, for simplicity.)

In your own code, if you set a breakpoint at the start of `Empfänger` (note that the 'ä' is permissible). Do you see any data?

If yes, your bindings should work. If no, you've found your problem there.

Unrelated, but: You can simplify your code greatly. Here's one example of how:

```
private List<Baustelle> Baustellen;

public BaustellePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Empfänger(
        new Baustelle(1, "herr 1", "auf 1", "ort 1", "strasse 1", "42", "50", "good"),
        new Baustelle(2, "herr 2", "auf 2", "ort 2", "strasse 2", "42", "50", "good"),
        new Baustelle(3, "herr 3", "auf 3", "ort 3", "strasse 3", "42", "50", "good"));

}

private void Empfänger(params Baustelle[] baustellen)
{
    var baustellenListe = new List<Baustelle>();
    baustellenListe.AddRange(baustellen);
    Baustellen = baustellenListe;
}
```

(`GetBaustellen` is gone, as is the (public?) `baustellen` field.)